# Where to Install Reporting Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

To use Reporting Service integrated with SharePoint, where to install Reporting Service?

Suppose that SharePoint env. has two physcical servers: application and database server.

Should reporting service be installed 
On the application server? or On the database server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt matter. However you must install the reporting services addon for SharePoint on the WFE (Front-End Server) if you want to use the "SharePoint integrated mode".
You can find more infos [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7825.sharepoint-2010-ssrs-infrastructure-reporting-services-integrated-mode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

SSRS itself must be installed on a SharePoint Server, not your Database Engine server (unless it also has SharePoint installed on it, which isn't advisable).